# USB Keyboard doesn't work until I manually inspect its device file

Tags: usb, keyboard, devices, usb-device, ttyusb

So I have a USB Keyboard that I built myself which runs the [qmk keyboard firmware](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware). I would preface this by saying that it's possible that this is a bug in the keyboard firmware. However, since the keyboard appears to work normally with windows, and because I can get it working by running linux commands (i.e. not changing anything on the keyboard side) I think this is probably an issue on the linux side.

Essentially, the keyboard doesn't work until I manually inspect the device file in Arch.

A few relevant logfiles from booting up the computer with the keyboard already plugged in (and no other USB devices plugged in except the internal camera):

- [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/c2YWWdCU)
- [dmesg | grep usb](https://pastebin.com/8rPYx4MJ)
- [dmesg | grep input](https://pastebin.com/TZskN0QL)
- [lsusb](https://pastebin.com/h91Djrw2)

At this point, the keyboard doesn't work due to the failed enumeration error. The keyboard is on USB 1-1.2.

The relevant lines are:

```
[    1.832175] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.905512] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.085461] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.265515] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.338846] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.518816] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.625860] usb 1-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[    3.218828] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[    3.632148] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 5, error -32
[    3.705494] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[    4.118807] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 6, error -32
[    4.119230] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[   17.805499] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   17.985547] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   18.165533] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[   18.238879] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   18.418843] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   18.525892] usb 1-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[   19.118769] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[   19.532187] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 10, error -32
[   19.605514] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[   20.018843] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 11, error -32
[   20.019332] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[   42.472082] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[   42.545439] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   42.725428] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   42.905429] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[   42.978812] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   43.158874] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   43.265778] usb 1-1-port2: attempt power cycle
[   43.858811] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[   44.272092] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 14, error -32
[   44.345501] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
[   44.758834] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 15, error -32
[   44.759116] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

After unplugging it and plugging it back in, those logs look like this:

- [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/KWAifXfY)
- [dmesg | tail](https://pastebin.com/6J1Cyi0Y)
- [dmesg | grep usb](https://pastebin.com/zAZ4NhkV)
- [dmesg | grep input](https://pastebin.com/vKtEjSi8)
- [lsusb](https://pastebin.com/9PQC05WG)

At this point, the keyboard is recognized by lsusb (USB ID ca04:0248), but typing still doesn't get it to work.

The way I can get the computer to register the input from the keyboard is by looking in dmesg and seeing that the keyboard occupies /dev/hidraw0, /dev/hidraw1,  and /dev/hidraw2. I then have to run `sudo cat /dev/hidraw2`, and from that point on everything functions normally (even after I kill cat). If I have other peripherals plugged in and the keyboard gets other hidraw numbers, I always have to cat the last one (for example, with my USB mouse also plugged in, the keyboard gets /dev/hidraw5, and that's what I then have to `cat` to get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas about what inspecting the device in the filesystem is doing that causes it to function normally? I'm aware it would be pretty simple to write a udev rule to do this every time the keyboard is plugged in, but I'd like to fix the underlying issue if possible.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to ask on kernel mailing list, or even report a bug for hid subsystem. If you do this, please leave a link here for further readers. I'm curious too.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I have no idea how to even go about accessing the kernel mailing lists! And I was reluctant to report a bug because I'm not even sure what the bug is (i.e what the reason for the issue is).

Comment: The bug is that keyboard doesn't work until you `cat` this file. Don't be afraid that it turns out to be invalid or something: you'll learn something new, and then there's a chance someone in future will stumble upon similar problem, and will also learn something from this report. I'm not sure, but I think the correct subsystem to report is Drivers → USB, i.e. [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers).

Comment: okay, I submitted a bug at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204823